# What is the number of levels in merge sort?

Tags: sorting, mergesort

I am confused what is the number of levels (height of the tree) in merge sort.

Somewhere I have seen it is given ceiling function of the $\log{2}{n}$ but  where it is written it is $\log{2}{n} + 1$

Can anyone explain what is the correct way.

Comment: Have you checked out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25633114/how-come-the-height-of-recursion-tree-in-merge-sort-lgn1 ?

Comment: @AshwanthKumar There it has not shown the difference between them.

Comment: @rcgldr then why here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25633114/how-come-the-height-of-recursion-tree-in-merge-sort-lgn1 it is given (log2(n)) + 1 is correct.

Comment: I deleted my prior comments, as I'm adding an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ceiling function is needed to handle the case when n is not a power of 2.

The answer in

[How come the height of recursion tree in merge sort lg(n)+1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25633114/how-come-the-height-of-recursion-tree-in-merge-sort-lgn1)

is misleading because each node in a binary tree consists of a value and two links (either of which may be null), while each stack frame in a recursive top down merge sort consists of 0 values and two indexes, iterators, or pointers.

As for the formula, if there is a check for the base case of sub-array size == 1 made by the caller, including the initial call, such as

```
    if(end-begin > 1) call mergesort();
```

then the formula is number of stack frame levels = ceiling(log2(n)).

If the check for the base case is done only at the top of mergesort, then the formula is number of stack frame levels = 2 + ceiling(log2(n)). Consider the case of n = 7, there are 5 levels of stack frames, if you include the initial call to mergesort. With top down merge sort, recursion continues until sub-array size is reduced to the base case of one element, in which case it returns:

```
level
1                           0,6
2             0,3                         3,6
3      0,1          1,3             3,4          4,6
4      ret       1,2   2,3          ret       4,5   5,6
5                ret   ret                    ret   ret
```

Comment: Can you also help me in https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/109253/exact-complexity-of-merge-sort